# Making a breaker li in between a list of li

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an dynamic list where I want to make an breaker list somewhere in the middle of it, but I can't figure out how to style a specific li amongst others?

Here is what i am trying to accomplish:

```
<ul id="games">
    <li class="myturn">Test 1</li>
    <li class="myturn">Test 2</li>
    <li class="breaker" style="height:3px;"></li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 3</li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 4</li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 5/li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 6</li>
</ul>
```

Can this be done? I cant get it to work. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What CSS have you tried? This is quite easily done, but it would be cool if we could see your current approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
.breaker{
    list-style-type: none;
    border:1px #000 solid
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bB52W/1/

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it with markup. You are using markup for styling and that's a nono. Just add a class to the last myturn element and add margin-bottom: 10px;

```
<ul id="games">
    <li class="myturn">Test 1</li>
    <li class="myturn breaker">Test 2</li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 3</li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 4</li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 5</li>
    <li class="theirturn">Test 6</li>
</ul>

.breaker{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bB52W/3/)

Comment: @Mooseman Adding a class and adding an element is different. Maybe markup was the wrong word to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>

#games li {
   /* your style for all LI's */
}

#games .myturn, #games .theirturn {
}

#games .breaker { 
    height: 3px;
}

</style>
```

you could also just fill your `<li>` with `<hr>`
which produces a horizontal line, still availible in `html5` and usefull. 
usally like this..

---

it has `display:block;` by default.

Comment: According to the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org), `Element hr not allowed as child of element ul`.

Comment: bääm! yes, same as div not inside A. but it is inside `<li><hr></li>`

Comment: an well, there is a reason why `<hr>` is not allowed direct under `<ul>`, often menus are produced out of it, and menus do not have <hr>, but they have menu items in a list <li> with breakers ^^